# iPhone layout issue with Cordova project for iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, layout, screen

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ak38Q.jpg
[image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPYpi.jpg

I’m porting an RPG Maker MV game to iOS and I’ve been able to get it to work for the most part. The resolution is 1280x720 and I’m testing on an XS Max. When I launch the game there’s a white bar on the side of the game and I can scroll in that area to center the screen. I’m very new to Xcode and don’t know how to fix this. I want the game to be centered and not be scrollable.

A post suggested putting this in the index.html: `<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height">`

And this in the config.xml: `<splash height="1125" platform="ios" src="res/screens/ios/land-2436x1125-screen.png" width="2436" />
<splash height="640" platform="ios" src="res/screens/ios/land-1136x640-screen.png" width="1136" />
<splash height="750" platform="ios" src="res/screens/ios/land-1334x750-screen.png" width="1334" />
<splash height="1242" platform="ios" src="res/screens/ios/land-2208x1242-screen.png" width="2208" />
<splash height="1536" platform="ios" src="res/screens/ios/land-2048x1536-screen.png" width="2048" />
<splash height="768" platform="ios" src="res/screens/ios/land-1024x768-screen.png" width="1024" />
<splash height="640" platform="ios" src="res/screens/ios/land-960x640-screen.png" width="960" />
<splash height="320" platform="ios" src="res/screens/ios/land-480x320-screen.png" width="480" />
<splash height="2436" platform="ios" src="res/screens/ios/port-1125x2436-screen.png" width="1125" />
<splash height="1136" platform="ios" src="res/screens/ios/port-640x1136-screen.png" width="640" />
<splash height="1334" platform="ios" src="res/screens/ios/port-750x1334-screen.png" width="750" />
<splash height="2208" platform="ios" src="res/screens/ios/port-1242x2208-screen.png" width="1242" />
<splash height="2048" platform="ios" src="res/screens/ios/port-1536x2048-screen.png" width="1536" />
<splash height="1024" platform="ios" src="res/screens/ios/port-768x1024-screen.png" width="768" />
<splash height="960" platform="ios" src="res/screens/ios/port-640x960-screen.png" width="640" />
<splash height="480" platform="ios" src="res/screens/ios/port-320x480-screen.png" width="320" />`

This didn’t work for me. Atleast the game was centered however it was zoomed out of scale and didn’t look correct. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: A screen with the wrong layout would be very helpful for others to see what exactly is wrong and how it can be fixed :)

Comment: Sorry, just added a link at the top of the post. :)